# jQuery filter JSON by variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, text

I'm building af custom store locator in WordPress.

I'm trying to filter some JSON objects where the value of a property matches af variable.

I've got a navigation bar generated by WordPress:

```
<ul id="store_list">
    <a class="cat-item" href="#">Denmark</a>
    <a class="cat-item" href="#">Austria</a>
    <a class="cat-item" href="#">Germany</a>
</ul>
```

The JSON is:

```
var jsonStr = '[{'title': 'Jeans Store DK', 'country': 'Denmark'}, {'title': 'Footwear', 'country': 'Austria'}, {'title': 'Accessories', 'country': 'Australia'}]'
```

When i click the link in the navigation I wan't to grab for instance "Denmark" and search for every store in the JSON where "country" is "Denmark". I then wan't to output this to a div with class .post-excerpt. So far I've got:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#store_list .cat-item').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var loc = $(this).text();
        var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
        var map_data = $.grep( json, function( n, i ) {
            return n.country === loc;
        });

        $('.post-excerpt').text(JSON.stringify(map_data));
    });
});
```

The problem is it only returns "[]" but if I set var loc = "Denmark" for instance, the code works. So I can't figure out to parse the loc variable to the grep function.

Thanks.

Comment: `console.log( loc )` both in `click` and `grep` callback

Comment: Hi. The console returns the name of the country i click on. The var map_data returns [].

Comment: What if `console.log( n.country , loc )`? What are the values?

Comment: The values are then: "Denmark Austria", new line "Austria Austria", new line "Germany Austria" and new line with "Denmark Austria"

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. I changed click selector to $('#store_list a') and then it worked! Thanks for your help!